# Deleting matrix column - out of memory

Tags: matlab, memory, matrix

I've got a large matrix of the form `A(1:n^2,1:n^2+1)` with `n=150` and I want to cut away the last column:

```
A=A(1:n^2,1:n^2);
```

This produces an "out of memory error". I already tried

```
A(:,n^2+1)=[];
```

But got the same error message.
I need to multiply the matrix with a vector of lenght n^2 and it is therefore crucial that A becomes quadratic.

Maybe someone knows an efficient way for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut the last column, one good way is to use the keyword `end`:

```
A(:,end) = [];
```

BUT it seems to cost a very long time ... I don't know why (maybe it calls realloc internally?). I don't have any 'out of memory' error with Matlab2013 (even with your second try).

For your problem, you may not need to cut the last column, just take the right slice of A:

```
B = A(:,1:end-1)*v;
```

But if you still have a 'out of memory' error, maybe it is because the maximal usable memory for Matlab is too low; use command `memory` to see if it is the case. In all cases, your problem seems to be very big, so refer to the help page concerning [Resolving Out-of-Memory Errors](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html)

Comment: Okay, first of all thanks for your answers. In the meantime I realized, that removing the last coloumn is not the problem - It's the amount of elements in general. Maybe I should have mentioned, that I'm building a Poisson-Matrix with ALOT of zero elements. Matlab hast implemendet functions for building diagonal matrices (spdiags) which saves them WAY more efficent. In addition there is also a single function which constructs exactly the matrix I need (gallery('poisson',n)).
Thanks anyways!